# Pulso sobre x de ventana, aparece pregunta, pero siempre se cierra programa

Tags: java, eclipse, windows10

Dentro del constructor de mi clase, tengo este método donde tengo recogidos todos los eventos que han de ocurrir al interactuar con la ventana.

En mi programa, al pulsar sobre la esquina superior derecha, sobre la x, aparece mi `JOptionPane` correctamente y preguntándome que deseo hacer.

Pero al pulsar sobre si,no,o sobre su x, da igual lo que haga, siempre se me cierra el programa. Aunque le responda que no, se cierra. ¿Donde esta el fallo en mi código?.

Según creo que yo todo lo que pusiese dentro de public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) es lo que se ejecutaría si pulso sobre cerrar ventana, de hecho, el `JOptionPane`, aparece, pero ni me hace caso a mi respuesta.

Mi idea cuando estoy programando esto seria que después de pulsar si, hiciese antes algo antes de cerrarme el programa por completo, como por ejemplo salvarme en un fichero mis datos de mis `JTextField`, etc, cosas mías, da igual, solo lo explico para que se vea la idea que llevo al escribir mi código. Y lógicamente si pulso no, no cerrarme el programa. Porque ahora mismo me lo cierra, da igual lo que responda. Gracias.

```
public void comportamientoEventosVentana() {

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Ventana Activada ");
        }

        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Ventada Closed Dispose");
        }

        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

            System.out.println("Ventana Closing");

            // pregunta
            int confirmed = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿ Quieres salir del programa ?", "cerrar programa", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

            if (confirmed == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                dispose();
            } else if (confirmed == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                // ha pulsado que noa
            } else if (confirmed == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
                // ha pulsado cancelar
            }       
        } 

        public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Ventana Desactivada");
        }

        public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Windows de Maximizada a Normal");
        }

        public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Windows de Normal a Maximizada");
        }

        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Windows Abierta");
        }

    }); // fin del addWindowListener
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando se habla de un componente de tipo `JDialog`, `JFrame` o `JInternalFrame` no es solo cuestión de implementar el [WindowListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html), ademas de esto debes definir el Comportamiento que deseas ante el "evento" de `windowClosing`

la forma en que `windowClosing` funciona es

1. enviar el evento a los Listeners
2. ejecutar el evento definido en el valor [getDefaultCloseOperation()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#getDefaultCloseOperation()) ([`DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`, `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`,`EXIT_ON_CLOSE` o `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html))

Por defecto los JFrame reaccionan utilizando el valor: [`HIDE_ON_CLOSE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html), sin embargo la mayoria de IDE cambian estos comportamientos a [`EXIT_ON_CLOSE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html) o [`DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html)

Para cambiar la forma en que un [JFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html),`JDialog` o `JInternalFrame` reacciona (en este caso, lo que deseas es que no cierre y para ello se debe utilizar [`DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html#DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE) ) se debe cambiar la forma en que el [JFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) se ejecuta ante el evento de `windowClosing` esto se logra de esta forma:

en el código de inicialización de la ventana deberás cambiar el `DefaultCloseOperation`:

```
/**
 * Creates new form 
 */
public JFrameExample() {
    //INICIALIZA Y CREA LOS COMPOENENTES DEL UI
    initComponents();        
    // nota ahora NOSOTROS DEBEMOS DEFINIR EL COMPORTAMIENTO DE CLOSE 
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

mas detalles en: [setDefaultCloseOperation(int) JAVADOC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int))

Comment: Efectivamente, ese era el problema. Cambie esa linea en el constructor y ahora funciona correctamente. Gracias.